# Base classing a synchronous controller into an async controller to hide complexity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
class MyBaseController : AsyncController
{
    // ... 
}

class SimpleController : MyBaseController
{
   public ActionResult MySyncAction()
   {
   }
}
```

I *ALWAYS* have to do one thing, **OperationX()**. This is a long standing operation for *ALL* my requests. It's values are different based on many things, but that's a technical detail.

I'd like to do that in an ASync fashion, and then call the controller's action method in the regular way. We have a ton of code in the SimpleController world, and we have hundreds of controllers and routes, etc, so it's no-go to convert all this code into ASync.

The quesiton, therefore is, how do I intercept an action coming to MyBaseController's MySyncAction and then invoke MyBaseController's Async action *ALWAYS*, and then only on completion, of the async action in the basecontroller, do I then call the MySyncAction of SimplerController.

Is this possible, what's the best way?

Comment: I think I cannot fully follow your question. Do you want to perform some action prior to the main action, or in parallel? If it is a "long standing operation", I guess it does not make sense to run in prior to the main action, right? I think in that case a HttpHandler might be an option for you, have you considered that?

Comment: Prior to the main action. the main action is quick, the prior action is the long standing one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to call the SimpleController's MySyncAction after the BaseController, then couldn't this be done using a FilterAttribute instead?

Here is an example of a custom filter attribute that does some logging...
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs

```
[MyFilterAttribute]
class SimpleController : AsyncController
{
   public ActionResult MySyncAction()
   {
   }
}
```